# How to select with 2 decimal places, but keeping zero with no decimal places

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to select some data and format with 2 decimal places, but when the data is NULL or ZERO, I want to have no decimal places.

For example:

```
1200 should return 1200.00
0 should return 0
NULL should return 0
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN COALESCE(number,0) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE CAST(number AS decimal(10,2)) END as "My number"
FROM Mytable
```

but the results are all with 2 decimal places:

```
1200 is returning 1200.00
0 is returning 0.00
NULL is returning 0.00
```

it seems like it's executing THEN and ELSE together, not one or another...

Comment: Your query looks working fine https://dbfiddle.uk/uZ8UItVQ

Comment: I think that presentation of results should be done in the presentation layer of your application, not in the database. My 2 cents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query works on numbers, and truncates them to a given number of decimals. How these numbers are actually *displayed* when printed highly depends on the setup of your database client. Eg, as demonstrated by SelVazi, your query works in this db fiddle, but not in the client you use.

If you want full control over the display, you can turn these numbers to strings, using [formatting function `to_char`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html):

```
select my_number,
    case 
        when my_number is null or my_number = 0 then '0'
        else to_char(my_number, 'FM99999990.00')
    end as my_new_number
from mytable
```

| my_number | my_new_number |
| --- | --- |
| 1200 | 1200.00 |
| 0 | 0 |
| *null* | 0 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CJqnrV4Q)